# R loops with multiple conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I would greatly appreciate any support on the following task.

So, I have a `tibble` of the following structure:

```
  A tibble: 380,586 × 4
Groups:   Year, SitcRev3Product [2,072]
    Year Economy SitcRev3Product  Index
   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>            <dbl>
 1  2015 004     001             0.108 
 2  2015 004     012             0.0053
 3  2015 004     017             0.0003
 4  2015 004     022             0.0662
 5  2015 004     024             0.0049
 6  2015 004     034             0.0212
 7  2015 004     037             0     
 8  2015 004     041             0.256 
 9  2015 004     042             0.137 
10  2015 004     043             0.0299
ℹ 380,576 more rows
```

My task is to create a variable that compares the `Index` for `Year == 2022` for each `Economy` and `SitcRev3Product` codes with the mean value of the `Index` for the previous 3 periods (e.g. 2019-21).

For instance, in case of `Economy == 004` and `Product == 001` I need to divide value of `Index` for 2022 by `mean(Index[2021],Index[2020],Index[2019])`. But those values for the previous 3 periods must be for the same economy(004) and same product(001).

What I have (unsuccessfully) done so far is the following:

```
Index_df |>
  group_by(
    Economy,
    SitcRev3Product
  ) |> 
  mutate(
    Index_2022_to_mean = Index / mean(
      dplyr::lag(Index, n = 3) + 
      dplyr::lag(Index, n = 2) + 
      dplyr::lag(Index, n = 1)
      )
  )
```

I wanted to ask the community to help me to move in the right direction with developing the code. I have been thinking about `for loops` and functions, but thought that there may be another elegant solution within the `tidyverse` universe.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please re-check your `Index_df` reprex generation? It not working is one thing, but it's bit difficult to understand what kind of row layout you had in mind. 8 rows? 11 rows? 900 rows?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this comment. I changed representation of the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this (you don't need loops in this case):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(Year == 2022, Economy_code, Product_code) %>% 
  summarise(mv = mean(Value)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(is2022 = ifelse(`Year == 2022`, "is 2022", "another year"), 
         `Year == 2022` = NULL) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from =  is2022,
              values_from = mv) %>% 
  mutate(diff_val = `is 2022` - `another year`)
```

You will get something lke this:

```
# A tibble: 63 × 5
   Economy_code Product_code `another year` `is 2022` diff_val
          <int>        <int>          <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1            4            1           5.86       1.5   -4.36 
 2            4            2           7         NA     NA    
 3            4            3           3.83       9      5.17 
 4            4            4           4.89       3.5   -1.39 
 5            4            5           4.67      NA     NA    
 6            4            6           3.57       8      4.43 
 7            4            7           4.11      NA     NA    
 8            4            8           5.71       0     -5.71 
 9            4            9           4.57       5      0.429
10            5            1           5.5        4     -1.5  
# ℹ 53 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Used data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- tibble(
  Year = sample(c(2015:2022), size = 500, replace = T),
  Economy_code = sample(c('004':'010'), size = 500, replace = T),
  Product_code = sample(c('001':'009'), size = 500, replace = T),
  Value = sample(c(0:10), size = 500, replace = T)
)
```

Comment: Thanks everyone who commented. This gave me food for thought. I managed to change my other code based upon what you suggested. Re this particular challenge, I think `pivot_wider` is the key.

Comment: @dkolkin welcome. It is common at SO to upvote and/or accept answers that suit you